# Having trouble getting a click event to run in aframe

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, game-development

I am trying to write an inventory system for a game using the AFrame library. I have a custom component that is set up to set the item i'm picking up to invisible and turn the in hand item visible. However when ever it runs it won't work.

Currently, i have a click eventlistener set up check when clicked. When clicked it is set to set the target item invisible (el) and the object in hand visible (handObj). It appears as tho the click function isn't evening running as I have a console.log set up to just check if the function ran or not.

Edit: I created a glitch with an example project
https://glitch.com/~tundra-ironclad

```js
var hands = [null, null];

AFRAME.registerComponent('pickUp', {
    schema: {
        handObj: {type: 'selector', default: ''},
        id: {type: 'string', default: ''}
    },

    init: function() {
        var el = this.el;
        var data = this.data;   

        el.addEventListener('click', function() {
            //pickup="target= #right
            console.log("hello");

            if(hands[0] == null) hands[0] = data.id;
            else if (hands[1] == null) hands[1] = data.id;
            else break; 

            el.setAttribute('visible', 'false');
            data.handObj.setAttribute('visible', 'true');

        });
    }
});
```

```html
 <a-box id="left1"
     color="#AA0000" class="clickable"
     position="8.000 0.200 7" depth = ".25"  height = ".25" width = ".25"

     event-set__enter="_event: mouseenter; material.color: #FF0000"
     event-set__leave="_event: mouseleave; material.color: #AA0000"

     pickUp="handObj: #left2; id: left"
    >
```

I don't understand why the click function isn't working at all since i have copied the formatting from tutorials and those components work fine.

Comment: It needs complete example to reproduce. Your snippet doesn’t show full context like for example how and where the cursor component is used, necessary to trigger events on entities. https://glitch.com/~aframe is a good option

Answer (score 0):

Your example freezes for me, but try `pick-up` instead of `pickUp`. HTML attributes are case-insensitive. We should add a warning for that.